# how to close autocomplete dropdown by button if it is opened

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

For an unknown reason the button does not close jquery ui combobox.

Steps to reproduce this behavior:

1. Open http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox in IE9.
2. Select the combobox on right side.
3. Click the dropdown [▼] button to open it.
4. Click again the dropdown [▼] button.

Observed:

> dropdown menu is still opened

Expected:

> dropdown menu should be closed.

Code contains:

```
if (input.autocomplete("widget").is(':visible')) {
    input.autocomplete('close');
    return false;
}
```

But for an unknown reason `input.autocomplete("widget").is(':visible')` is always false.

How can I make the dropdown close if the button in clicked and the dropdown is opened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the variable:

```
var isVisible = false;
```

and add this code inside the click event function of `$( "<a>" )`:

```
if(isVisible == true)
{
    input.autocomplete( "close" );
    input.blur();
    isVisible = false;
}
else
    isVisible = true;
```

Comment: Thank you. If dropdown is opened by autocomplete, not by button click, using this requires two clicks in button to close dropdown. How to fix this so that single click can used to close dropdown in this case also ?

Comment: Also opposite is true: if dropdown is closed since item is selected, this reqires two click in button to open dropdown again. How to open dropdown with single click in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript alternative:

```
 document.getElementById('my_autocomplete_element').blur();
```